# NAPS2 OutOfMemoryException in Large Files Scan

Tags: c#, scanning

Using NAPS2: 6.1.2.25834:
HighScan Driver: TWAIN

While im scanning Large files it popups this exception

> NAPS2.Scan.Exceptions.ScanDriverUnknownException: An error occurred
> with the scanning driver. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of
> memory. at System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetHbitmap(Color background) at
> System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetHbitmap() at
> NAPS2.Scan.Images.BitmapHelper.CopyToBpp(Bitmap b, Int32 bpp) at
> NAPS2.Scan.Images.ScannedImageHelper.SaveSmallestBitmap(Bitmap
> sourceImage, ScanBitDepth bitDepth, Boolean highQuality, Int32
> quality, ImageFormat& imageFormat) at
> NAPS2.Scan.Images.ScannedImage..ctor(Bitmap img, ScanBitDepth
> bitDepth, Boolean highQuality, Int32 quality) at
> NAPS2.Scan.Twain.TwainWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__2(Object
> sender, DataTransferredEventArgs eventArgs)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task
> task) at NAPS2.Worker.WorkerService.d__8.MoveNext() at
> Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> NAPS2.Scan.ScanPerformer.d__7.MoveNext()

How could i fix this, is it about bitmapheader size issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you are handling file > 3gb. Configure the project to x64 processor type.
You can do this by right clicking on project -> properties and setting processor type to x64

32bit program can handle upto 3gb file only.

Hope my answer helps, don't forget to upvote.

Comment: Files are 1 || 2 gigs, so it seems to be elsewhere the issue. Thanks anyway.